# How to exclude Spring Security for Spring Boot Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-security, mockmvc

Spring Boot version: 2.2.6.RELEASE

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [IndexController::class])
```

One thing I would like to do is disable security for the tests.

```
@WebMvcTest(value =  [IndexController::class], secure = false)
```

and

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
```

Both of them are do not compile because of secure properties is deprecated.

I do not want mock my security service class in every test

I tried

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [TestController::class], excludeAutoConfiguration = [SecurityConfiguration::class])
```

and

```
@WithMockUser
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I disable security ?

Comment: *Deprecated* is only a warning, it should compile without problems.

Comment: If your endpoints have been developed with security checks, your Junits should be manage such use cases, otherwise you are not covering all required tests. Why `@WithMockUser` does not work?

Comment: when i use a secure properties (deprecated) code does not compile because of spring version.

Comment: yes @WithMockUser annotation is does not work